# $\cos(x)\cos(mx)$ is a polynomial in $\sin(x)^{2}$ with degree $\le (m-1)/2$

Tags: trigonometry

For all $m \ge 1$ odd show that:

1) $\cos(x)\cos(mx)$ is a polynomial in $\sin(x)^{2}$ with degree $\le (m+1)/2$

2) $\frac{\sin(mx)}{\sin(x)}$ is a polynomial in $\sin(x)^{2}$ with degree $\le (m-1)/2$

Hint: Use induction!

---

My idea was to use some addition theorems but i dont know which. Maybe someone here has an idea how to proof it.

I proved 2) by using

- $\sin(mx+2x)=\sin(mx)\cos(2x)+\sin(2x)\cos(mx)$
- $\sin(2x)=2\sin(x)\cos(x)$
- $\cos(2x)=1-2\sin(x)^{2}$

AND 1)...

So please help me to prove 1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your probably have a typo on your statement (1),

> ... with degree $\leq (m-1)/2$

, which should actually be

> ... with degree $\leq (m+1)/2$

A simple check, when $m=1$, $\cos(x)\cos(mx)$ is a first-degree polynomial of $\sin^2x$

========================================================

Now assume (1)&(2)  holds for $m-2$,

$$
   \cos(x)\cos(mx) = \cos(x)\left\{\cos[(m-2)x]\cos(2x) - \sin[(m-2)x]\sin(2x)\right\}
$$

Let me use $P_n(x)$ denote a polynomial of $x$ with degree $\leq n$.

The first term on the RHS:
$$
\cos(x)\cos[(m-2)x]\cos(2x) = P_{\frac{m-1}{2}}(\sin^2x) (1 - 2 \sin^2 x) = P_{\frac{m+1}{2}}(\sin^2x)
$$

The second term on the RHS:
$$
\begin{aligned}
\cos(x)\sin[(m-2)x]\sin(2x) = & \cos(x)[ P_{\frac{m-3}{2}}(\sin^2x) \sin(x) ]\sin(2x)\\
                            = & P_{\frac{m-3}{2}}(\sin^2x) 2\sin^2(x)\cos^2(x) \\
                            = & P_{\frac{m+1}{2}}(\sin^2x)
\end{aligned}
$$

Thus $\cos(x)\cos(mx)$ is also a $ P_{\frac{m+1}{2}}(\sin^2x)$.

Comment: @FabianSchneider, you are right. I missed a bracket there.

Comment: @FabianSchneider, you should combine those 2 proofs together. First, we assume for up to $m$, both 1) and 2) are correct (which can be easily verified for $m=1$). Then we prove that 1) and 2) are still correct for $m+2$.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^{imx}=(\cos x+i\sin x)^m=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom mk i^k\cos^{m-k}x\sin^kx.
$$

Taking the real part and noting that only the terms in even $k$ remain, we see that every term of $\cos x\cos mx$ is a product of even powers of $\cos x$ and $\sin x$.